# How do I build a web app and API together for a service that mostly relies on authenticated requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, authentication, oauth

I am trying to build out a video collaboration platform. I wish to design it in such a way that there is an API and my web app is like a 'third party' app.

The way I see it working is with three main components..

- JSON API written in Ruby
- Web App written in Ruby/Rails
- Front End Application in Coffeescript

I want to be able to make authenticated requests for resources such as 'projects'

As of right now, I imagine the front end application talking to the Rails app in order to get an authenticated request, and then the front end app using that authenticated request to call the API.

I have a few questions about this architecture.

1. If I plan to open the API up later, is OAuth what I should be using?
2. If so, what would the request flow look like?

I am only asking these questions because OAuth looks to be the standard and I can only see it in terms of authenticating a third party app to access resources in another app.

I guess I am mostly looking for some guidance, as I can build applications, I am just no security expert. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I can tell you what I'm doing right now in my project:**

1. Rails API (JSON); you can use rails api gem, grape or full rails framework.
2. Single page web app using AngularJs (it can be anything else you feel comfortable with, like backbone, emberjs, etc.)

**How I'm authenticating the user:**

1. The user posts to **/login** with username and password
2. The Rails part authenticates the user (by the username and password), creates an access token (persist it in a table, with expiration time, for example, 30 mins) and returns it to the user.
3. Each request from the client side (angularjs part) is passed with a Token authentication header like so: **Authorization: Token token=[the token goes here]**
4. The rails api uses to token to get the associated user
5. If the token has expired or is invalid, it returns 401 (unauthorized); once the angularjs part intercepts a 401 it redirects the user to the login page.
6. If the request is authenticated, the expiration time is reset to 'now' so the 30min i'm talking about acts like 30 mins of inactivity

You can do a lot more with the access token - you can do roles, like Admin, User, etc. and limit the user's access to resources.